# Google Oauth 2.0 on server to specific account without login and redirect

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-oauth, autologin

I am trying to using some youtube api to edit some vedio's imfomation of a specific account.It means whoever call my function can edit the vedio infomation of this account.So I have done the function that getting the token and refresh token from google and refresh token per hour.It seem work well to keep updating the token , but I'm wondering if there is some way that I can get new token (or some way to auth oauth) from server.Maybe some verification from iam etc.. thanks!

Comment: You will need three items. The Client ID, the Client Secret, and the Refresh Token. With those items, you can do anything at the client or at the server eg create new Access Tokens.

Comment: thanks , I've solve the problem.